# Why does md:hover:text-indigo-xxx have no effect on anchor elements?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, flowbite

I'm using Flowbite with plain HTML & CSS and without any frontend framework.

I tried the following code snippet from Flowbite:

```html
<nav class="bg-white border-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-900">
  <div class="max-w-screen-xl flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between mx-auto p-4">
    <a href="https://flowbite.com/" class="flex items-center space-x-3 rtl:space-x-reverse">
        <img src="https://flowbite.com/docs/images/logo.svg" class="h-8" alt="Flowbite Logo" />
        <span class="self-center text-2xl font-semibold whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">Flowbite</span>
    </a>
    <button data-collapse-toggle="navbar-default" type="button" class="inline-flex items-center p-2 w-10 h-10 justify-center text-sm text-gray-500 rounded-lg md:hidden hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:focus:ring-gray-600" aria-controls="navbar-default" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
        <svg class="w-5 h-5" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 17 14">
            <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M1 1h15M1 7h15M1 13h15"/>
        </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="hidden w-full md:block md:w-auto" id="navbar-default">
      <ul class="font-medium flex flex-col p-4 md:p-0 mt-4 border border-gray-100 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 md:flex-row md:space-x-8 rtl:space-x-reverse md:mt-0 md:border-0 md:bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 md:dark:bg-gray-900 dark:border-gray-700">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-3 text-white bg-blue-700 rounded md:bg-transparent md:text-blue-700 md:p-0 dark:text-white md:dark:text-blue-500" aria-current="page">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-3 text-gray-900 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 dark:text-white md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-3 text-gray-900 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 dark:text-white md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-3 text-gray-900 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 dark:text-white md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-3 text-gray-900 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 dark:text-white md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I tried to change the hover color to indigo on the menu items as follows:

```html
<a href="#" class="...text-gray-900 ... md:hover:text-indigo-700 md:p-0 ...">Pricing</a>
```

But the color doesn't seem to change when I hover. Strange enough it works with the blue color like this: `md:hover:text-blue-700`

So why does it work with blue color, but not with indigo or purple color?

Comment: Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].

Comment: I tried your example, and it actually works. Pay attention to the "md" breakpoint and the "dark" one.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. Could you try with the snippet in the following code: https://gist.github.com/bouchtaoui-dev/90b55ee81396134d2f357a9f9de94c6f#file-hover-html ? That would be awesome.

Comment: Found the problem, I only linked Flowbite css. I needed to link tailwindcss too :/ Sorry guys, but thank you very much for your help.